# Exponential distribution with exponential parameter

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Let X be  an  exponential  random  variable  with  parameter  Λ,  which  is  itself  a  random  variable  with distribution Exponential(β).  Find a formula for the conditional density of Λ given X=x, and identify its type (i.e.  its name and parameter(s)).

I made some good progress but then got stuck. I started with Bayes' Rule, and wrote

$$ f(Λ|x)=\frac {f(x|Λ)f(Λ)}{f(x)} $$
Now the numerator expressions seemed simple enough. $f(x|Λ) = Λe^{-Λx}$, and $f(Λ) = βe^{-βΛ}$. I'm having a hard time finding an expression for $f(x)$. I thought about integrating over the possible values of Λ:
$$ f(x) = \int_o^\inftyΛe^{-Λx}dΛ$$
but I know this is incorrect. How to approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1)**
$$ f(\lambda |x)=\frac {f(x|\lambda)f(\lambda)}{f(x)} \propto f(x|\lambda)f(\lambda)$$

$$=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \beta e^{-\beta \lambda} \propto 
\lambda e^{-\lambda (x+\beta)} $$

so $\lambda \sim \Gamma(2,x+\beta)$ [Gamma_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)

$$f(\lambda|x)=\frac{(x+\beta)^2}{\Gamma(2)}\lambda^{2-1} e^{-\lambda (x+\beta)}$$

**Method 2)**

$$ f(\lambda |x)=\frac {\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \beta e^{-\beta \lambda}}{f(x)}  $$

$$=\frac {\beta \lambda e^{-\lambda (x+\beta)} }{\beta \frac{\Gamma(2)}{(x+\beta)^2}} $$

$$=\frac{(x+\beta)^2}{\Gamma(2)}\lambda^{2-1} e^{-\lambda (x+\beta)}$$

Sine 
$$f(x)=\int f(x,\lambda) d\lambda=\int f(x|\lambda)f(\lambda) d\lambda$$

$$=\int \beta \lambda e^{-\lambda (x+\beta)} d\lambda$$
$$=\beta\int  \lambda^{2-1} e^{-\lambda (x+\beta)} d\lambda$$

$$=\beta \frac{\Gamma(2)}{(x+\beta)^2}$$

Comment: Can you explain what you did, I don't follow

Comment: You do not need calculate $f(x)$ since it is look like a constant in density $f(\lambda|x)$. so I calculate the core of density(every part that depend on $\lambda$) and then change it to valid density.